# Ubuntu Classic, possible to have just big icons like in Windows 7?

Tags: 11.04, gnome, gnome-classic

I like how in Windows 7, only icons are shown in the taskbar/panel. Is it possible in Ubuntu (11.04)?

Also I suppose it will be great to be able to group windows from the same program into 1 icon and have some sort of preview, also like in Windows 7 or even Unity with Preview enabled

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be looking for [Dockbarx](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=101604). It's a panel applet you can add to your bottom panel in place of your window list, and it should be able to duplicate all this functionality for you. (Also, to make the icons bigger, just increase the size of the panel then.)

You could also try removing the bottom panel and replacing it with Docky in panel mode, but then you won't get previews. Docky is a bit nicer-looking and easier to set up though, in my opinion.